# Import from multiple sources

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import all icons from different sources as `Icons`, something like that:

```
import * as Icons from {"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid","@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular","@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands"}
```

but it is not a correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an aggregator file i.e. `icons.js`

```
import like from 'likeIcon.js';
import menu from 'menuIcon.js';
import bird from 'birdIcon.js';

export default {
  like,
  menu,
  bird
};
```

Then you can import all the icons you need

```
import {like, bird} from './icons.js';
```

You can also import the icons object

```
import icons from './icons.js'
```

and then use them as `icons.like` or `icons.menu`

Comment: With as is it : import {like, bird as Icons} from './icons.js' or import {like, bird } as Icons from './icons.js'

Comment: It seems you want to bundle all the icons together, which you can do by `import icons from 'icons.js'.` Then you can use it as `icons.like` or `icons.menu`. I recommend never using the * syntax when importing